# Set a typeface of a MenuItem

Tags: android, menuitem, typeface

I have subMenus:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        SubMenu subMenuFile = menu.addSubMenu("Font type");

        SubMenu subMenuEdit = menu.addSubMenu("Font size");
        subMenuEdit.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_FONT_SIZE, Menu.NONE, "Change size of font");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I want to set their typeface. Can I do it? Menu.XML file doesn't support the attribute android:typeface="serif". The compiler says: "Error: String types not allowed (at 'typeface' with value 'Arial')"
Then I have done this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        SubMenu subMenuFile = menu.addSubMenu("Font type");

        for(int i = 0; i < fontFaces.length; ++i) {
         subMenuFile.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_FONT_TYPE, Menu.NONE, Html.fromHtml("<b>html</b>"));
        }

        SubMenu subMenuEdit = menu.addSubMenu("Font size");
        subMenuEdit.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_FONT_SIZE, Menu.NONE, "Change size of font");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I have seen, that the submenu supports different styles, but the application finishes with an error. Here is the log:

```
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.util.EventLog.writeEvent(Native Method)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2204)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1800)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 10:04:18.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 10:04:22.393: ERROR/InputDispatcher(67): channel '406c4fb8 android.htmleditor/android.htmleditor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-12 10:04:22.393: ERROR/InputDispatcher(67): channel '406c4fb8 android.htmleditor/android.htmleditor.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-12 10:04:23.263: ERROR/InputDispatcher(67): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=175, events=0x8
```

How can I set a typeface of a MenuItem?

Comment: i dont think there is any method to set font style as you did in code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant change the style of a menu item. You can only change the text and the menu icon of a menu item. If you wan to change the look and feel, i am afraid that you have to create a new custom implementation of yours.

For starters, i will suggest override the menu key and show your own custom view instead of default android menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom layout for your item and use typeface that you need through xml.

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24807645/4958167

And here is [an article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-custom-font-textview/) how to create typefaced text view.

Answer (score -2):

dynamically `setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);`through `setTypeface()`method we can set the font style for the views.

Comment: where do you see view? I have MENUITEM! It isn't an subclass of the class View! Look: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html. Try to found the subclass Menu there