# how to change font of menu item in android?

Tags: android, menuitem, typeface

I am having a menu item "**CLEAR**" in my app. I am using different typefaces in my app. I want to set a specific typeface for this menu item. Is it possible? Then how?

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942533/how-to-change-custom-font-of-android-menu-item

Comment: try this code it's working fine [Set Custom Font in Menu Item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30681846/3374796)

Comment: none of the solutions are working

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu will help you.