# How do i add custom font on menu item in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been trying to add a font to my menu items and have tried few solutions i found but none of them worked for me.

Method 1 :[How to set custom typeface to items in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668346/how-to-set-custom-typeface-to-items-in-navigationview/30681846#30681846)

Method 2:

**Menu XML**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/filter_button"
        android:title="action_notification"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navmenu_cat"
                android:icon="@mipmap/categories"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="@string/categories" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navmenu_date"
                android:icon="@mipmap/calendar"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="@string/date" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**MyClass**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.work_history, menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ar_regular.ttf");
            SpannableStringBuilder title = new SpannableStringBuilder(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
            title.setSpan(face, 0, title.length(), 0);
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
            menuItem.setTitle(title);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942533/how-to-change-custom-font-of-android-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

you can use this lib https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy. It will set the default font to your menuItem when you attach it to a context

Answer (score 0):

```
There is a library https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy,

Add this dependency to your build gradle

dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}

Then in your activity override this method

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```